# How to use `expect` at the top level of a Minitest test?

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

I'm writing some tests using Minitest's 'spec' style. I'd like to be able to have a one-line test using the 'expect' method. For example (invalid):

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rspec/expectations/minitest_integration'

describe Tuple do

  describe "A tuple with w=1.0" do   
    a = Tuple.new(42)    
    expect(a.x).to eq 42        
  end

end
```

I know that I can do this:

```
describe Tuple do

  describe "A tuple with w=1.0" do   
    a = Tuple.new(42)    
    it { expect(a.x).to eq 42 }
  end

end
```

But I might as well just `it { assert_equal(42, a.x) }` for an equivalent one-liner.

Is there a recommended way to be able to use `expect` in place of `it` ? Or should I just alias the method?

Comment: Usually the `it` contains a description (e.g `it("does thing") { }`, would you care about this or not really?

Comment: @maxpleaner Not if the code/assertion itself is expressive, and that is my reason for elevating the `expect` method. "It expect a.x to equal 42" doesn't read as nice as "expect a.x to equal 42."